# Exact functor on inclusion

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}$ be abelian categories. Let $F:\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be a covariant exact functor.

My questions:

1. How to show $F$ preserve monomorphism?
2. Let $\iota_A:A\to B$ be an inclusion. Does $F(\iota_A)=\iota_{F(A)}$, where $\iota_{F(A)}:F(A)\to F(B)$ is the inclusion on $F(A)$?

Comment: What do you mean by "an inclusion"?

Comment: Inclusion means $\iota_A(x)=x:A\to B$.

Comment: And what does that mean for a general, not necessary concrete, abelian category?

Comment: You are right, we cannot talk about inclusion for non concrete, abelian category. Consider a concrete, abelian category, I would like to know the answer for question 2.

Answer (score 4):

If $A \to B$ is a monomorphism, then you have an exact sequence $0 \to A \to B.$
Since $F$ is exact, you get the exactness of $0 \to F(A) \to F(B)$ which means that $F(A) \to F(B)$ is a monomorphism.